# Best approach for branching strategy for TFS with three areas DEV, Stabilization and Production?

Tags: branching-and-merging, tfs-2015, branching-strategy

We are migrating source control from subversion to TFS 2015. Our development efforts will be divided into 2 teams: one will only perform new development/enhancements and the other team will only do defect fixes.

Can anyone suggest a branching strategy to merge these 2 different efforts?
One branch (Development) will always have newer code changes than the branch used by the other team that's performing defect fixes only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion,  **Branch for Release** is most suitable for your situation.

Your team creates branches to support an **ongoing release**. This is the next most common case where you need to create a branch to stabilize for a release. In this case, your team creates a branch before release time to stabilize the release and then merges changes from the release branch back into the main source tree after the software is released.

```
Main
-DEV
-release1
...
-release2
```

Comment: Once the release branches are merged, do you recommend deleting them? I can see building up a large list over time.

Comment: BTW, I hear the term feature branch? How is that different from release?

Comment: Well, it's based on the size of your team, the frequencies of your release. Usually recommend to keep branches around for when you are actively developing. However, you can also delete the old branch, after all deleting a merged branch is cheap and won't make you lose any history.